# Mongo _id in class definition

Tags: php, php-mongodb

This is my first time shoving objects into Mongo - I am using PHP. I know that MongoDB adds the `_id` variable to an array while inserting using the `MongoCollection::insert()` function. the problem is this:

if I define a public variable named `_id` the variable remains `NULL` upon insert

```
class MognoTest {
    public _id;
    public foo;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->foo = 'bar';
    }
}

$obj = new MongoTest();
$Mongo->collection->insert($obj);
var_dump($obj)
$found_obj = $Mongo->collection->findOne();
var_dump($found_obj);
```

The `var_dump()`s on `$obj` and `$found_obj` both return an object with `_id=NULL`. If I comment out _id in the class definition, the code runs properly and both `var_dump()`s print a MongoID.

I want to define in the class an _id to make my code clearer and make my code hinting on Netbeans work properly. Is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: Have you tried setting the value for `_id` before inserting it into the database?

Comment: I plan on using the  `MongoID` auto-generated by the MongoDB as my primary key and I'll be using in my code later on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got a solution, though i don't like it to be honest -- to me it seems inelegant.

```
class MognoTest {
    public _id;
    public foo;

    public function __construct($load = NULL){
        $this->foo = 'bar';
        if ($load != NULL && isset($load['_id']))
            $this->_id = $load['_id'];
    }
    public function insertPrep(){
        if ($this->_id === NULL)
            unset($this->_id);
    }
}

//create object, prep, insert
$obj = new MongoTest();
$obj->insertPrep();
$Mongo->collection->insert($obj);
var_dump($obj)

//get object back and reload as object
$found_obj = $Mongo->collection->findOne();
$new_obj = new MongoTest($found_obj);
var_dump($new_obj);
```

I consider this solution inelegant because the programmer must now remember to add a line of code before each insert `MongoTest::insertPrep()`. I also tried adding a `public function __insert()` magic function but that didn't pan out :(

I still look for a better solution. But for anyone with this problem, here is a fix even if this fix isn't the elegant one I was hoping for.